# передача данных из коллекции java в jquery (Autocomplete)

Tags: jquery, json, java-ee

Добрый день!
Изучаю jquery(Autocomplete), и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
если у меня список значений в заданном массиве в скрипте то все работает:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            var tags = ["tag1", "tag2", "atag3", "btag4", "aaa5"];
            
            $('#acInput').autocomplete({
                source: tags
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Но мне необходимо получать данные из коллекции java, например обратившись к контроллеру по ссылке. Читал, что с коллекцией java не будет работать, и как вариант перевести коллекцию в json формат.

Пробовал писать использовать такой контроллер:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/tags", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getTags() {
        List<Tag> tags = (List<Tag>) tagService.getAll();
        List<String> tagsName = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Tag tag : tags){
            tagsName.add(tag.getName());
        }
        String jsonStr = new Gson().toJson(tagsName);
        return jsonStr; 
    }
```

и в скрипте указывал ссылку на контроллер:

```js
$(function() {
            
    $('#acInput').autocomplete({
                source: '/tags'
    })
 
});
```

и ничего не работает.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, как это все запустить. И какие вообще есть варианты передавать данные в скрипт из коллекции java, чтобы это все работало? К примеру, у меня на этой jsp есть доступ к необходимой коллекции, могу ли я ее использовать в скрипте для решения данной задачи не вызывая отдельно метод контроллера?

Заранее прошу прощение, может не совсем понятно изложил проблему.

Спасибо

Дополнение:
переписал метод getTags
@RequestMapping(value = "/tags", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getTags()  {
        List tags = (List) tagService.getAll();
        List tagsName = new ArrayList();
        for (Tag tag : tags){
            tagsName.add(tag.getName());
        }
        String jsonStr = new Gson().toJson(tagsName);
        System.out.println(jsonStr);
        return new Gson().toJson(tagsName);
    }

автоподстановка теперь работает, но показывает все теги. То есть сортировка не работает, а просто вываливает все данные.  Как запустить сортировку?

Comment: что  tags возвращает можете прилепить в вопрос

Comment: спасибо, добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в коде не хватает галочек для tags

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#acInput').autocomplete({
                source: 'tags'
            })
        });
</script>
```

Comment: галочки добавил но не работает

Comment: Какие вы подгружаете jquery?

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css">  как я понял контроллер возвращает в кривой кодировке, указал в дополнении к вопросу.

Comment: так все дело в кодировке

Comment: так а что с этим делать?

Comment: почему он вам возвращает 404 status code

Comment: метод контроллера возвращает строку, соответственно эта строка пихается в URL, а такой страницы не существует. Как-то так я это понимаю

Comment: переписал метод и автоподстановка теперь работает, но показывает сразу все теги, не сортируя.

Comment: супер, мой ответ помог?

Comment: да, спасибо , буду благодарен если поможете еще со следующим вопросом :)

Answer (score 0):

переписал метод

```html
@RequestMapping(value = "/tags", method = RequestMethod.GET) public @ResponseBody String getTags() { 
  List<Tag>tags = (List<Tag>) tagService.getAll(); 
  List<String>tagsName = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    for (Tag tag : tags){ 
      tagsName.add(tag.getName()); 
    } 
  String jsonStr = new Gson().toJson(tagsName);    System.out.println(jsonStr); 
  return new Gson().toJson(tagsName); }
```

автоподстановка работает. Вылезли другие проблемы но это наверное тема другого вопроса.